# Spivak's proof of change of variable

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus

I'm reading the proof of change of variable in Spivak's Calculus on manifolds.

In the last inequality of page 68, I think this proof assumed that $ f\circ g |\det g'| $ is integrable on $g^{-1}(V)$ . But Cannot understand why this is true. Can anyone explain why this function is integrable?